# How to override the auto assign public ip flag in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Is there a way where we can disable auto assign public ip flag in terraform script for a amazon EC2 instance?

Can we handle this scenario through script where we could have option to have no public IP address assigned in a subnet that defaults to having one assigned?

Comment: Have you tried setting `associate_public_ip_address` to `false` in the `aws_instance` resource?

Comment: Should I set above property to false as shown in the below tf extension file? 
data "aws_instance" "efiletps" {
  filter {
    name    = "vpc-id"
    values  = [ "${var.vpc_id}" ]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["TUKPRDWEB015"]
  }
  associate_public_ip_address = false
}

data "aws_instance" "updates" {
  filter {
    name    = "vpc-id"
    values  = [ "${var.vpc_id}" ]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["TUKPRDWEB014"]
  }
  associate_public_ip_address = false
}

Comment: @BrunoSchaatsbergen For associate_public_ip_address attribute Is it supported only in particular terraform version and above that?